# What unique value does Cramer's rule offer?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

When I was studying linear algebra, the textbook first taught Gaussian elimination and then introduced Cramer's rule. Great, I learned two methods for solving systems of linear equations. However, when I studied numerical analysis, I found out that Cramer's rule is an inefficient method. It involves more computations than Gaussian elimination.

So, there is the question, why do textbooks still teach Cramer's rule? Is it simply to make students aware of the use of determinants? Or does it have other applications that Gaussian elimination cannot replace?

Comment: Cramer's rule is not inefficient itself. It depends how you compute the determinants. Cramer's rule is a scheme that can very easily be memorized , and it is elegant. Moreover , if we start with the main matrix , we know immediately whether the solution is unique.

Comment: It is a simple to remember algorithm - very non-mathmajor-friendly. God forbid you expect first semester students to comprehend elementary row operations.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your comment. "It depends on how you compute the determinants" - Does choosing an optimal method for calculating determinants make Cramer's rule involve fewer steps than Gaussian elimination? Are there any recommended books on this topic?

Comment: @Peter "If we start with the main matrix, we know immediately whether the solution is unique." - I'm not quite clear on this. Are there any recommended books that address this aspect?

Comment: As you mentioned, it's not practically useful for solving linear systems of equations because superior methods (such as Gaussian elimination) are available. People never use Cramer's rule in numerical analysis or scientific computing. Cramer's rule might occasionally be theoretically useful. For example, in Spivak's proof of the inverse function theorem in Calculus on Manifolds, I believe he uses Cramer's rule at the end to show that the inverse function is not just differentiable but in fact continuously differentiable. (I need to double check Spivak though.)

Comment: @AlvinL If we are only considering solving equations, I find that Gaussian elimination is relatively easy to learn. Cramer's rule, on the other hand, can be quite cumbersome as it involves calculating multiple determinants, which can easily lead to errors. Moreover, understanding Cramer's rule from the outset is not straightforward.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for your comment; it provides valuable insights. I will take a look at "Calculus on Manifolds."

Comment: Chronologically, students likely learn about up to 3x3 determinants in gymnasiums and setting up/solving 3x4 systems using Cramer's method for the unique solution. Hence, that's why it's easy to start off with such problems and slowly (usually second week) let them know that these systems are a tiny edge case and introduce them to some linear algebra magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cramer‘s rule is used in a lot of proofs. You can use it to get the $(i,j)$-th entry of the matrix $A^{-1}$ (see adjugate matrix), it be used to prove the that every smooth $C^1$ diffeomorphism is actually a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism. Furthermore, knowing the explicit entries of the $(i,j)$ entry of the inverse matrix can be used in a lot of proves, for example if you want to show that the inverse of a upper triangular matrix is upper triangular. There are a lot of small applications, but they are more on the theoretical side of maths.

Comment: Another proof that I've seen before that it is pretty hard to prove without cramer's rule is showing that the inverse of an integer entry matrix with determinant $\pm 1$ also has integer entries.

Comment: @AlanAbraham - For that you can use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem instead.